# How to debug Ext JS 4 error in console

Tags: javascript, extjs, user-interface, extjs4.2

One of the bug is not allowing the application to load fully. Error message is very generics which doesn't say clearly the module which has that issue :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null
>   `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null ext-all-debug.js:62557
>   Ext.define.setLabels ext-all-debug.js:62557
>   Ext.define.applyData ext-all-debug.js:62578
>   Ext.define.drawAxis ext-all-debug.js:61899
>   Ext.define.redraw ext-all-debug.js:60442
>   Ext.define.afterComponentLayout ext-all-debug.js:60382
>   Ext.define.notifyOwner ext-all-debug.js:37353
>   Ext.define.callLayout ext-all-debug.js:119598
>   Ext.define.flushLayouts ext-all-debug.js:119767
>   Ext.define.runComplete ext-all-debug.js:120253
>   callOverrideParent ext-all-debug.js:39
>   Base.implement.callParent ext-all-debug.js:4266
>   Ext.override.runComplete ext-all-debug.js:29267
>   Ext.define.run ext-all-debug.js:120234
>   Ext.define.statics.flushLayouts ext-all-debug.js:29275
>   Ext.define.statics.resumeLayouts ext-all-debug.js:29283
>   Ext.resumeLayouts ext-all-debug.js:31760
>   Ext.define.render ext-all-debug.js:28510
>   Ext.define.constructor ext-all-debug.js:29579
>   Base.implement.callParent ext-all-debug.js:4266
>   Ext.define.constructor ext-all-debug.js:33595
>   constructor ext-all-debug.js:4897
>   (anonymous function)
>   Ext.ClassManager.instantiate ext-all-debug.js:5485
>   (anonymous function) ext-all-debug.js:2112
>   Ext.apply.create ext-all-debug.js:3788
>   Ext.define.initViewport ext-all-debug.js:57187
>   Ext.define.onBeforeLaunch ext-all-debug.js:57159
>   Ext.define.constructor ext-all-debug.js:57099
>   constructor ext-all-debug.js:4897
>   (anonymous function) ext-all-debug.js:7794
>   createSingle ext-all-debug.js:9863
>   fire ext-all-debug.js:9818
>   Ext.apply.readyEvent.readyEvent.fire ext-all-debug.js:10052
>   Ext.apply.fireReadyEvent ext-all-debug.js:10130
>   Ext.apply.onDocumentReady ext-all-debug.js:10148
>   Ext.apply.onReady.fn ext-all-debug.js:6658
>   Ext.apply.triggerReady ext-all-debug.js:6644
>   Ext.apply.refreshQueue ext-all-debug.js:6177
>   Ext.apply.refreshQueue ext-all-debug.js:6207
>   Ext.apply.refreshQueue ext-all-debug.js:6207
>   Ext.apply.refreshQueue ext-all-debug.js:6207
>   Ext.apply.refreshQueue ext-all-debug.js:6207
>   Ext.apply.refreshQueue ext-all-debug.js:6207
>   Ext.apply.refreshQueue ext-all-debug.js:6207
>   Ext.apply.refreshQueue ext-all-debug.js:6207
>   Ext.apply.onFileLoaded ext-all-debug.js:6587
>   (anonymous function) ext-all-debug.js:2105
>   Ext.apply.injectScriptElement.onLoadFn`

The error points to the ext-all-debug.js file.
How do I find out which file of my application it points to ?

Tried to debug through inspector; but was not fruitful.

Comment: This is typically the kind of errors you get. I think after a while you just come to understand what certain things mean. If I were troubleshooting your application, I would assume it has something to do with a `store` and its `reader` and/or `model`. Posting your code would be helpful rather than just posting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ext-all-debug.js is the compilation of all Ext JS classes available in the framework. When you're debugging your app, it is much easier to use ext-dev.js instead; this file contains only the core, and all other classes are loaded dynamically using [Ext.Loader](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Loader). Note that just switching to ext-dev.js will not eliminate the bug, but it will allow you to pinpoint its location easy and quick.

It is also beneficial to set the browser debugger to break on unhandled exceptions. Combined with dynamic loading, you'll get a breakpoint right where the error is, and you can see immediately which class and method that is. This, the stack trace, and the scope variables should give you enough clues to find the cause for the exception.

I would also recommend taking a look at [Sencha Cmd](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/command), it can help you with managing the build process for your application.